# Laravel: Type error: Argument 1 passed to boolen given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, php-7.1

First time digging into Laravel and started with the API portion first.

Also keep note that I'm using the `Cyvelnet/Laravel5Fractal` package as well as `Laravel/Passport`.

Every time I call the `/announcements` portion of my API,specifically an object (I hope that's what you call `api/announcements/1`), I keep getting this jiggy error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Flarify\Transformers\AnnouncementTransformer::transform() 
must be an instance of
Flarify\Announcement, boolean given, called in C:\wamp64\www\flarify.dev
\vendor\league\fractal\src\Scope.php on line 407
```

Pointing to this line/function in my AnnouncementTransformer class specifically:

`public function transform(Announcement $announcement)`

Here is my AnnouncementTransformer class:

```
namespace Flarify\Transformers;

use Flarify\Announcement;
use League\Fractal;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;
use League\Fractal\Resource\Collection;
use League\Fractal\Resource\Item;


class AnnouncementTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    /**
     * List of resources possible to include
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $availableIncludes = [];

    /**
     * List of resources to automatically include
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $defaultIncludes = [];

    /**
     * Transform object into a generic array
     *
     * @var $resource
     * @return array
     */
    public function transform(Announcement $announcement)
    {
        return [

            'id' => $announcement->id,
            'user_id' => $announcement->user_id,
            'title' => $announcement->title,
            'message' => $announcement->message,
            'created_at' => $announcement->created_at->format('d M Y'),
            'updated_at' => $announcement->updated_at->format('d M Y'),

        ];
    }

    public function includeCreator(Announcement $announcement)
    {
        return $this->item($announcement->user_id, new UserTransformer());
    }
}
```

And my Announcement model:

```
namespace Flarify;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


/**
 * Class Announcement
 * @package Flarify
 *
 * @property int id
 * @property int user_id
 * @property string title
 * @property string message
 * @property Carbon created_at
 * @property Carbon updated_at
 *
 */
class Announcement extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'announcements';

    public function announcementCreator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

And also my AnnouncementController just in case:

```
namespace Flarify\Http\Controllers;

use Cyvelnet\Laravel5Fractal\Facades\Fractal;
use Flarify\Http\Requests\Anouncements\StoreAnnouncementRequest;
use Flarify\Http\Requests\Anouncements\UpdateAnnouncementRequest;
use Flarify\Transformers\AnnouncementTransformer;
use Flarify\Announcement;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Flarify\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AnnouncementController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $announcement = Announcement::all();

        return Fractal::includes('user')->collection($announcement, new AnnouncementTransformer());
    }

    public function store(StoreAnnouncementRequest $request)
    {

        $announcement = new Announcement;
        $announcement->user_id = 1;
        $announcement->title = $request->title;
        $announcement->message = $request->messages;

        $announcement->save();

        return Fractal::includes('user')->collection($announcement, new AnnouncementTransformer());
    }

    public function show(Announcement $announcement)
    {


        return Fractal::includes('user')->collection($announcement, new AnnouncementTransformer());
    }

    public function update(UpdateAnnouncementRequest $request, Announcement $announcement)
    {
        $announcement->title = $request->get('title', $announcement->title);
        $announcement->description = $request->get('description', $announcement->description);

        $announcement->save();

        return Fractal::includes('user')->collection($announcement, new AnnouncementTransformer());
    }

    public function destroy(Announcement $announcement)
    {
        $announcement->delete();

        return response(null, 200);
    }
}
```

Again, this is my first ever Laravel project and me putting what I learned in PHP OOP all in one go (MVC too).

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Also, this is my first post! (Woohoo?)

Comment: So you're making a GET request to `api/announcements/1` and `$announcement` is a boolean. I'm thinking your route model binding is not working (or you're not using the `SubstitueBindings` middleware). When you call `->collection()` rather than getting the `$announcement` object, it's getting `1` or `true`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I figured out what I did wrong and you helped me pave the way!

The issue was in my `AnnouncementController`.

I had put `->collection()` instead of `->item()` for my show and update methods.

I replaced:

`return Fractal::includes('user')->collection($announcement, new AnnouncementTransformer());`

With:

`return Fractal::includes('user')->item($announcement, new AnnouncementTransformer());
`

and my GET request on /announcements/1 returned the data I was expecting!